# Problem solving - coding interview question

Tags: python, algorithm

A XOR problem

You are given two positive integers X  and Y  without leading zeroes. You can perform an operation on these integers any number of times, in which you can delete a digit of the given number such that resulting number does not have leading zeroes. Let X′  and Y′ be two numbers that were formed after performing operations on X  and Y respectively.

You have to find all the unique pairs of X′  and Y′  whose XOR is zero.

Note: Two pairs of numbers (A,B) and (C,D) are considered different if and only if A!=C or B!=D .

Input format

First line: An integer T  denoting the number of test cases
Each of the next T  lines: Two space-separated integers X  and Y
Output format

For each test case, print the answer in a new line.
Constraints

1≤ T ≤ 101 ≤ X ,Y ≤ 1012

Sample input 1
212 10213 33
Sample output 1
31

For the test case 1,

Possible values of X' are [1,2,12]
Possible values of Y' are [1,2,10,12,102]
So, three pairs (1,1), (2,2), (12,12) have xor zero.

For the test case 2,

Possible values of X' are [1,3,13]
Possible values of Y' are [3,33] (We can generate 3 two times)
So, one unique pair (3,3) has xor zero.

```py
def XOR_Problem (X, Y):
    # do something
    return None # return Something

T = input()
for _ in xrange(T):
    X, Y = map(int, raw_input().split())

    out_ = XOR_Problem(X, Y)
    print out_
```

I have no idea how to solve this, gotten this as an Interview question and had 20 minutes to solve this. (this question was from a few months ago)

Comment: Given X=212, I would expect X' = [1, 2, 12, 21, 22, 212]. In general, the presentation of the problem needs a lot of work.

Comment: What do you call the XOR ? What is the XOR of 123 and 222 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote "You have to find all the unique pairs of X′ and Y′ whose XOR is zero.". If I'm understanding this correctly, this is only true if X' = Y', right?

But then you say "Note: Two pairs of numbers (A,B) and (C,D) are considered different if and only if A!=C or B!=D.". But since it must be the case that A=B and C=D, then there's no ambiguity here... so I'm puzzled by this comment.

I'm also a little puzzled by your example: you say for X=212 the "Possible values of X' are [1,2,12]"... but isn't 21 also possible (by deleting the last 2)?

However, assuming I understand the problem correctly, you can regard X and Y as strings (of length at most 3 and 4 respectively), and you want to find which non-contiguous substrings (i.e. strings obtained by deleting characters) are producible from both.

Because common substrings are of length at most 3 (and at least length 1), this seems easy enough to do in a brute-force manner. I mean, there's at most 2^3 - 1 = 7 non-empty strings producible from X, and at most 2^4 - 2 = 14 non-empty strings producible from Y that are of length < 4. You could just produce both lists, sort them both, and find common elements.

I would optimize this further if their lengths were bigger, but I think this is fine for a first pass.